# how to solve the following without a calculator

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is their a method for the required question except brute force ? (here $11$ terms gets multiplied as followed)

$$1\cdot(0.985)\cdot(0.97)\cdot(0.955)\cdot(0.94)\cdot(0.925)\cdot(0.91)\cdot(0.895)\cdot(0.88)\cdot(0.865)\cdot(0.85)$$

Comment: Not really. You could maybe do it in terms of Gamma functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Product), but that seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: any suggestions on approximations?

Answer (score 1):

If there wasn't an extremely intuitive method, I would guess that you multiply a even (decimal ending with an even digit) with another decimal ending with a 5 first, so that you at least will get one "0" at the end of your result.

Interested to see if a quirky method actually exists.

Comment: how about arithmetic mean greater the geometry mean    ,then 1*0.85 will be slightly less then 0.925   and using this analogy one gets series as (0.925)^11 =0.42 which is 0.01 more than the actual answer ... just wondering what about the lower limit?

Comment: I would ignore the $1$ term and multiply similarly. That gives $0.9175^{10}$, should be a bit closer.

Answer (score 0):

how about arithmetic mean greater the geometry mean    ,then 1*0.85 will be slightly less then 0.925   and using this analogy one gets series as (0.925)^11 =0.42 .If you are  wondering what about the lower limit?   then using similar lines GP is less than Harmonic prog. , so using 1 and 0.85 as 2 terms of HP yields harmonic mean as (0.919)^11  which is around 0.39 so the answer lies between 0.395 and 0.424 ... so  the avg of both which is 0.409 is a good approximation of the given product ...